# adding objects from different JLists to one JList

Tags: javascript, jbutton, jlist

I have three JList's, startersList, mainsList, and dessertsList. I also have a billList. I also have three buttons for the three JList's in order to add to the billList.

My problem is that every time I click any of the three button's it add's the object to the billList JList, however if I click add again it appears that the JList has 'reset' it's self because the object doesn't add its self on under the object that was added previously.

Here is the code for the Buttons:

```
btnAddStarter = new JButton("Add starter");
    btnAddStarter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel dlm1 = new DefaultListModel();
            billListGUI.setModel(dlm1);
            dlm1.addElement(startersListGUI.getSelectedValue());
        }
    });
    btnAddStarter.setBounds(18, 266, 200, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnAddStarter);

    btnAddMains = new JButton("Add mains");
    btnAddMains.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel dlm1 = new DefaultListModel();
            billListGUI.setModel(dlm1);
            dlm1.addElement(mainsListGUI.getSelectedValue());       
        }
    });
    btnAddMains.setBounds(18, 446, 200, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnAddMains);

    btnAddDessert = new JButton("Add dessert");
    btnAddDessert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel dlm1 = new DefaultListModel();
            billListGUI.setModel(dlm1);
            dlm1.addElement(dessertsListGUI.getSelectedValue());
        }
    });
    btnAddDessert.setBounds(17, 631, 201, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnAddDessert);
```

I think where I type "DefaultListModel dlm1 = new DefaultListModel();' is where the problem is but not sure.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new DefaultListModel your data gets lost.

Apply a ListModel on the same level as your button methods are and use it in the actionperformed method.